# Bluetooth Low Energy vs NFC

Tags: android, nfc, bluetooth-lowenergy

Does Bluetooth Low Energy also does the authentication as NFC, ( I mean, do we need to explicitly key in the password, or it does something auto authentication ) and transfers the data.

Can BLE can be a threat to the NFC.
What are the difference between the two?

Here I have listed few differences which I know

BLE/ NFC :

- Speed on which it communicates(fast/slow),
- protocol ISO, Setup time(fast/slow),
- power consumption (depends),
- Security (good/Better)

---

Does Bluetooth and BLE are two different hardware, or just the BT hardware behaves as BLE with specific libraries and protocol?

Comment: Here I have listed few diff which i know

BLE/ NFC : Speed on which it communicates(fast/slow), protocol ISO, Setup time(fast/slow), power consumption (depends), Security (good/Better)

Appreciated if someone can add in

Answer (score 7):

Can a car be a threat to airplanes? Yes, they both provide means of transportation, but you wouldn't want an Airbus A380 to go to the mall two corners away to fetch a batch of carrots, and you won't use a car to travel overseas...

The two are not competing, but rather complementary things. For example, with a device implementing both BLE and NFC, you could use the NFC to make easy and secure pairing of the devices...

Bluetooth Low Energy has a much higher range (we could even use devices as far as 30 meters in open space!), whereas NFC is for a lot shorter range.

> Does Bluetooth and BLE are two different hardware, or just the BT hardware behaves as BLE with specific libraries and protocol?

They are different, the only thing they have in common is the frequency range. The whole communication is different. However, there are chips that can use both, these are called dual mode chips (Texas Instruments CC2564 for example).

Comment: Thanks Gordon,for editing. @ppeterka, good, thanks for the answer. can you also let me know how BLE authenticates, do we manually need to punch in the key or auto authentication as in NFC

Comment: @Rahul I hadn't worked too much on this, but I think you can choose from several schemes, you can choose to use manual entry, or out-of-band authentication (like using NFC to make sure that is the exact device to talk to...)....

Answer (score 2):

> Does Bluetooth and BLE are two different hardware, or just the BT hardware behaves as BLE with specific libraries and protocol?

Bluetooth and BLE can be both supported on the same radio chip, but about everything about it is different, except that they both share the 2.4GHz ISM spectrum. Silicon designed to do only Bluetooth can not generally be forced to do BLE by loading different firmware, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Apple are supporting Bluetooth LE with iBeacons in iOS7.

They even let  you turn any Bluetooth 4.0 compatible iOS device into a beacon.

http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/19/inside-ios-7-ibeacons-enhance-apps-location-awareness-via-bluetooth-le